# Proper Fluid Templating in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, templating

My question deals specifically with connecting backend layouts and content elements and how to properly integrate them into the main content area of a website. Here is my current setup:

TYPO3 7.4 using the FLUID templating engine
Dynamic Content Elements (DCE) extension installed.

I have already placed elements such as the header and footer into partials and they are loaded into the main template via FLUID. I am currently stuck trying to figure out how I should template the main content area. It consists of one column, between the header and footer, but should contain different configurations of elements.

For instance, say for the first block, I would like a header followed by a row of 3 boxes placed side by side. In the second block, a header followed by a row, in which an arbitrary amount of boxes can be displayed, but at one time, only four (thus the user would have to horizontally scroll to see the others). It should look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGosd.png

**First attempt at a solution:**
I created the DCEs and a backend layout with two columns. Each column serves as a an input area for the two rows seen in the image. Then, I modified the Typoscript template to access these columns with **colPos** and saved them in variables using **styles.get.content**. Using FLUID, I could then implement them in the template and they could be outputted.

First of all, I have no idea if this is a valid usage of backend layouts, but I have a feeling that this is not how they were intended to be used. The columns are not truly columns, simply a means to target them with Typoscript, and thus have nothing to do with the structure of the page. Secondly, this method seems to be inefficient, since should I want to add another row to the page with other characteristics, the backend layout would have to changed to accommodate this. Thirdly, other pages could have varying amounts of these rows, which are essentially used to group elements. Depending on how complex the site becomes, this could mean many background layouts.

In sum, the question posed is:

1. Is this solution proper, and if not, how does one group elements in TYPO3 to achieve the explained goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the extension "Gridelements". Version 4 is on Github only but works with TYPO3 7.x.

My suggestion:

1. use one backend layout with only 1 column "Main content".
2. define your grids in Gridelements, for your case you need a 3-columns-grid and a 4-columns-grid. (look at manual for configuration)
3. insert the grids on your page and within the grids you DCEs.

I mostly use different backend layouts for enabling/disabling sidebars or separating upper and lower content areas...